# Why do these nested functions not execute in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Came across a really weird issue in Firefox. I have some code written in the following format

```
function wrappingFunction() {
  function a() {
    //some code
  }
  function b() {
    //some code
  }
  function c() {
    //some code
  }

  var foo = a();
  var bar = b(foo);
  c();
}

wrappingFunction();
```

This structure works fine in IE and Chrome, however wouldn't execute in Firefox. As a start to degugging i placed a `console.log` call at the top of the wrapping function just to see if this was executing. After placing this the code suddenly starts working.

```
function wrappingFunction() {
  console.log("yes i work");

  function a() {
    //some code
  }
  function b() {
    //some code
  }
  function c() {
    //some code
  }

  var foo = a();
  var bar = b(foo);
  c();
}

wrappingFunction();
```

Tried this on other machines just to check it was not something wrong with my FF install, but same behavior on all. My version of Firefox is also up to date.

I am kind of scratching my head now because I can not figure out what is happening. Is the way I have structured this program inherently invalid? Or is this some kind of Firefox behavior I am unaware of?

Why is this happening?

Comment: Works perfectly here. Just tried with some `console.log` and with `a` returning `'stuff`', no issue.

Comment: Probably `//some code` has something to do with the main problem... Can you reproduce it in a plunkr?

Comment: No errors on the console?

Comment: @MinusFour no errors :/ just doesnt execute without the random console.log in there

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @KingMob I wouldnt really want to put my entire code here as I wouldnt expect anyone to go through debugging the whole thing (thats my job!) Just put this question on to see if anyone had come across this behavior before or had any ideas. My first thought was it was the structure but if its not ill have to do more digging

Comment: The structure is fine. So the problem is in the code that you've snipped. You don't have to, and shouldn't, show the entire code, but I'd suggest pruning the code until you have a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think on a checklist:

- Are you sure that the code is being executed after the page finished loading? What happens in FF if you put the  code inside a onload event?
- Does any of these functions depends on a DOM element?
- Have you tried executing the functions isolated (calling only function a, only function b...)?
- What is the error that appears n console?